# Rest API: Inserting value to MySQL database with ExpressJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, express

I have this simple API for MySQL database run on ExpressJS.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

var mysql = require('mysql')
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'andri',
  password: '12345',
  database: 'andri'
});

app.get('/employees', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  connection.query('select * from users', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});

app.get('/employees/:id', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('select * from users where id=?', [req.params.id], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});

app.post('/employees', function (req, res) {
  var postData = req.body;
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users (`id`, `userid`, `fullname`, `usergroup`, `emailid`, `mobile`, `title`, `created_at`) VALUES (NULL, '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);", 
  postData, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});
```

I can test using POSTMAN that GET function (both employees/ and employees/:id) end points working fine. But the POST function

```
{
    "userid": "PROJ-12345",
    "fullname": "Eko Andri S",
    "usergroup": "IT",
    "emailid": "eko.andri@xxx.or.id",
    "mobile": "0811111111",
    "title": "Intern",
    "created_at": "2018-05-30T01:59:17.000Z"
}
```

get this result on the POTSMAN:

```
{
    "fieldCount": 0,
    "affectedRows": 1,
    "insertId": 8,
    "serverStatus": 2,
    "warningCount": 0,
    "message": "",
    "protocol41": true,
    "changedRows": 0
}
```

The above records recorded successfully in the database, but the value for each field is "?" with no quote; except for the timestamp which recorded correctly.

If I remove the quote for the ? in the INSERT line, I get the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: I appreciate your help but I try many combinations, and it said "You have an error in your SQL syntax". This syntax doesn't work "INSERT INTO users, [postData.id, postData.userid,etc] VALUES [NULL,'?','?',...]. Could you be more spesific what should I put between the ? mark. Thanks

Comment: Look at the examples from the library, (they don't add quotes around the ? and they also pass an array as second argument and not an object, that was, what i tried to say)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems, you are missing the body parser part which *parses the JSON, buffer, string and URL encoded data submitted using HTTP POST request*. You can find more info about body-parser [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Add below lines in your code and make sure you have installed body-parser.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Then in your `app.post` part

```
app.post('/employees', function (req, res) {
  var postData = req.body;
  postData.created_at = new Date();
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?",
  postData, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results.insertId); // Auto increment id
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Hi Deepak, it works perfectly. Sorry for the late respond as I just came back from school.

Answer (score 0):

Since **question mark (?)** is enclosed with single quotes, its is considered as a string, that why **question mark (?) is stored in your database.** Checkout this following approach by inserting rows with Auto increment primary key.

```
app.post('/employees', function (req, res) {
  var postData = req.body;
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", 
  postData, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results.insertId); // Auto increment id
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please remove the created_at field while doing post request and let me know. In case of error kindly share it with full trace.